# Visual Studio 2012: missing Windows Phone 8 Unit Test App project template

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I want to create a unit testing project for my Windows Phone 8 project.
My problem is that I can't find the unit test app project template from my new project dialog, as in here http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_create_unit_tests_for_Windows_Phone_with_the_Visual_Studio_Unit_Testing_Framework

is there a way to install these templates ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved it by re-installing (repairing) the SDK. true

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 or above installed

(1) http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2797912

(2) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/01/31/windows-phone-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-2012-update-2.aspx